# Factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[4]{3}]$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $p$ a prime number such that $p≡3$ (m0d $4$), and $p>3$, discuss the factorization of $(p)$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$, where $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$.

I know that the ring of integers in this case is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[4]{3}]$,and  by Kummer's theorem, one can decide the decomposition based on factorization of $f(x)=x^4−3$ (mod $p$).

There are five possible cases:

1. $f(x)$ factors into $4$ linear factors in $\mathbb{F}_{p}[x]$.
2. $f(x)$ factors into $2$ linear factors and $1$ irreducible quadratic factors in $\mathbb{F}_{p}[x]$.
3. $f(x)$ factors into $2 $ irreducible quadratic factors in $\mathbb{F}_{p}[x]$.
4. $f(x)$ factors into $1 $ linear factor and $1$ irreducible cubic factor in $\mathbb{F}_{p}[x]$.
5. $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_{p}[x]$.

I don't know how to go further than this!

Comment: One linear and one irreducible cubic factor is impossible?

Comment: I forget this case, thank you!

Comment: You didn't say the word unramified. Is it what you mean with Kummer's theorem ? The splitting field is $\Bbb{F}_p(\sqrt{3},i,3^{1/3})$. The first step is to find $\Bbb{F}_p(\sqrt{3},i)=\Bbb{F}_p(\zeta_3,i)=\Bbb{F}_p(\zeta_{12})$.

Comment: @reuns Its $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]3)$ not $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[6]3)$

Comment: A typo I meant $\Bbb{F}_p(\sqrt{3},i,3^{1/4})$. Once we know $\Bbb{F}_p(\zeta_{12})$ (which depends solely on $p\bmod 12$) it suffices to check if it contains $3^{1/4}$ to know the splitting field thus the factorization of $x^4-3$.

Comment: Surely case 4 is impossible. The Galois group over $\Bbb{Q}$ is dihedral of order eight. But case 4 implies the existence of an element of order three in the Galois group by Dedekind. All the other cases occur with primes $p<20$ already. Chebotarev says something nice about the relative frequencies of the cases. Because the Galois group is non-abelian class field theory says that we cannot tell which $p$ belongs to which case **by congruences alone.** We need at least quadratic form, possible something else. If quadratic forms suffice, an efficient algorithm is to summon Will Jagy and wait.

Comment: Deleting my answer because I found [a duplicate target](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2560807/11619).

Comment: When $p\equiv3\pmod4$ it is a decision between case 2 and 3. As per reuns' comment case 1 implies $p\equiv1\pmod{12}$, and the answers to the linked question exclude case 5 also.

Comment: Because the group $D_4$ has two 2-cycles and three elements of cycle type $(2,2)$ Chebotarev's density theorem says that the relative frequencies of cases 2 and 3 are $2:3$ in favor of case 3. I don't know if that still applies when we restrict ourselves to prime $\equiv3\pmod4$.